# Cannot find a list of data selectors for Gutenberg editor

Tags: plugins, block-editor

I've been searching through WordPress docs and internet but I can't find a list of available data stores for Gutenberg editor. Example data store in use:

```js
wp.data.select('core/block-editor');
```

I know a few other data stores other than `core/block-editor` but I want to know all the available options as well as selector functions for the stores.

So where can I find the above specified list with documentation for Post/Page Gutenberg editor and Widgets Gutenberg editor?

My Scenario: I have some blocks which generates CSS based on the blocks' settings (attributes). The CSS is generated using JavaScript and I need to save the CSS by calling an API endpoint when user hits the save button in the Widget editor page. So my problem is I haven't found a way to know when user clicks on save button.

Comment: The term for these are data stores, not data selectors. As for a full list, I do not believe one exists. The closest is searching the gutenberg codebase for store registrations, or looking through the reference for individual uses. Is there a particular use case you need this for? There may be alternative ways to do what you want that don't require this, if not then the context will help to get better answers and avoid misunderstandings. For example I realise now you might not be referring to stores but the individual functions e.g. `wp.data.select('core/block-editor').canMoveBlock()`

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks for correcting the terminology, I wasn't sure about the terms myself. And I have updated my question with the correct terms and additional explanation about my problem. Please read it and provide me further guidance if you don't mind. So the documentation for them really might not exist then. That's too bad. I will look through the codebase and document my findings here when I have time. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Ah this is an X Y problem, you never actually wanted to know the full list but were hoping it would provide the solution to your real problem :( Would it not make sense to store the generated CSS in an attribute, or store what's needed to generate it so it can be generated on the frontend or in PHP? I do not understand why this would require an AJAX API request, or why this would lead you to searching store selector functions. Also I would consider only saving when hitting the save button an anti-pattern and unexpected behaviour, a bug even, I suspect there is more info not being shared

Comment: Think of it this way, this behaviour would be extremely unusual for a shortcode, therefore it doesn't make sense in a block either, blocks are meant to be self contained, they aren't the literal manifestation of data that lives elsewhere, you should be able to render a block using only its attributes if it's built in javascript, additional API requests should not be necessary to save it and you run the risk of breaking the editors data model and UX expectations

Comment: @TomJNowell I understand what you mean. But the way I'm doing it is when user changes a setting, a CSS for all the blocks gets generated and inserted in the head tag (for preview). When user saves a post/page, again a CSS is generated and the CSS is saved in the post's meta by calling an API (this is the reason I was calling an API endpoint). The reason I'm saving all the CSS for all blocks in a single meta is when the post is visited, I add the CSS to head tag using `wp_add_inline_style` function.

Comment: And about your suggestion, to store the generated CSS in an attribute, I did consider that but I thought there might arise a problem when updating block attributes. But now that I think about it again that might not be the case. I will first try that method then. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: as long as you treat the attribute as a string and don't try to "nest" things or store objects you're fine doing that